# Pydev finding some modules

Tags: python, import, pydev, pythonpath

I have just configured PyDev 3.9.0 with Eclipse 4.4.1 on Mac and it seems it is only finding some of the dependencies.

Command line everything works fine:

```
$ python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from zipline.api import order, record, symbol
```

But in PyDev only symbol is found in the zipline/api module.

So it turns out, "symbol" is in the file zipline/api.py but the other methods are loaded via the **init**.py with initialization code:

```
__version__ = "0.7.0"

from . import data
from . import finance
from . import gens
from . import utils
from . import transforms
from . algorithm import TradingAlgorithm

from . import api

try:
    ip = get_ipython()  # flake8: noqa
    ip.register_magic_function(utils.parse_cell_magic, "line_cell", "zipline")
except:
    pass

__all__ = [
    'data',
    'finance',
    'gens',
    'utils',
    'transforms',
    'api',
    'TradingAlgorithm',
]
```

This seems not to be picked up by PyDev. The same interpreter is configured in PyDev as I use command line.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Thanks a lot,

Per

Comment: But how does `api.py` get those `order` and `record` identifiers?  The `__init__.py` you show has no mention of them, and you don't show the relevant subset (or any part of) the crucial `api.py` source.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a module called zipline, which probably conflicted with the package zipline. After removing my own module PyDev could resolve completely.

Thanks!